# Manifest merger failed error in Android gradle

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest-merging

I am getting `manifest merger failed` error. I have tried most suggested way to fix below error with dependency but unable to resolve.

#### Below is my Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.plainnotes"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    // additional libraries
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha03'
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
}
```

#### This is the Error message that I received

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-22:19 to override.
```

Comment: I think you're mixing new androidx and older version of android support library.

Comment: Probably you are right but when I removed `androidx` and kept `butterknife` it is still giving the same error

Comment: @CodeLover By the way you can check the issue in merged manifest tag. Open your manifest file and the bottom left  you will see text, merged manifest. Click it and it will tell you the issue and the possible fix too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because you are using a **different library** for android. Made refactor to AndroidX packages for all library

**With this**

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

// additional libraries
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha03'
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha03"
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
```

to this

```
//Android support libraries.
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

As of **Support Library** and AndroidX Library are diffrent one. So use only one type of library.

Comment: This is perfect solution. However, I would like to know where I can check all `androidx` dependency versions and other details.

Comment: I found another way to migrate.. `Android Studio > Refractor > Migrate to AndroidX...`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Two lines in gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

and add this in manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="your.package.uri">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx">
```

Comment: Where it will go in manifest? within the `<application... />` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing new androidx package with older version of android support library. You can find a guide and new androidx package on following link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate